How to configure input devices when using Wayland instead of Xorg?
I'm using KDE desktop environment, and I have recently switched from Xorg to Wayland. The compositor is KWin.
I'm concerned about configuring my mouse and keyboard properly, because obviously it can't be now done with xorg.conf as it was before.
I wasn't able to find any documentation related to configuring KWin when using it w/o Xorg. There are advantages for me in using Wayland, but I'm really confused about it's design. I can't understand which programs now take care of my hardware, when there's no Xorg server. For example, the graphics backend: it uses DRM automatically, but where can it be configured?
As another example, this was my keyboard configuration, where I had keyboard layout set, and few other options:
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "evdev"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option "XkbLayout" "us,tr"
    Option "XkbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
    Option "GrabDevice" "false"
EndSection

Without Xorg, where do I configure my input drivers so the Wayland compositor will use the correct settings?
Another part of config which I also need, is related to blacklisting virtual mice from being added to the session (I use them for different purpose):
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier     "ignore virtual mouse"
    MatchProduct     "melon69-virtual-mouse"
    MatchIsPointer      "on"
    Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

Is it possible to configure a Wayland compositor for the same behavior (blacklisting input devices), or I have to go by removing user permissions on the device nodes?

Thanks for your help!
